# move in vector <T>

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl

I need to move all elements which have a сertain `CPU_type` in the beginning of vector. How to do that? I know I am using move method incorrectly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>

struct T {
    int number;
    std::string CPU_type;
    int size_of_hard_drive;
    int size_of_RAM;
};

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector <T> v(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> v[i].number >> v[i].CPU_type >> v[i].size_of_hard_drive >> v[i].size_of_RAM;
    }
    string type_of_CPU_to_move_forward;
    cin >> type_of_CPU_to_move_forward;
    vector <T> ::iterator it;
    for (it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it) {
        if ((*it).CPU_type == type_of_CPU_to_move_forward) {
            vector <T> ::iterator it1 = it;
            move(it1, it1, v.begin());
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition

Comment: Or [`std::stable_partition()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition), or [`std::sort()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)